# Proxy requests from origin to CDN

Tags: web-hosting, cdn

Reading Google's web.dev article on Optimize Largest Contentful Paint (https://web.dev/optimize-lcp), there is a section that talks about using CDNs which says

> While image CDNs are a great way to reduce resource load times, using a third-party domain to host your images comes with an additional connection cost. While preconnecting to the origin can mitigate some of this cost, the best option is to serve images from the same origin as your HTML document. **Many CDNs allow you to proxy requests from your origin to theirs**, which is a great option to look into if available.

I'm not clear exactly what they mean in this scenario as it seems to imply that origin will proxy requests to the CDN and therefore the client will only connect to the origin.

Normally a CDN will be a reverse proxy to the origin, hoping the serve the cached content from the CDN rather than pulling the content from the origin.

What the web.dev article seems to be suggesting is the other way round, whereby the client will not connect to the CDN and will instead only connect to the origin. In this scenario I don't see what value the CDN adds. Clearly I'm missing something but I'm not sure what.